# Increase maximum execution time using Nginx and HHVM

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, hhvm

I'm using hhvm 3.8.0 and nginx 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. I noticed that with default configuration you can't execute a script more than 120 seconds, then nginx shows a 502 Bad Gateway error page. How can I increase maximum execution time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hhvm couldn't read your configuration, so it take the defaults.

```
/usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/php.ini --config /etc/hhvm/server.ini --user www-data --mode daemon -vPidFile=/var/run/hhvm/pid
```

syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting TC_DOLLAR_CURLY or TC_QUOTED_STRING or '"' in /etc/hhvm/server.ini on line 79\n

Just comment any line and works great:
; hhvm.log.access.*.format = %h %l %u % t \"%r\" %>s %b